# NextJS Filesystem Routing Semantic

Tags: routes, next.js, semantics

In the NextJS world you can route a page such as `/hello` using:

Method A:

```
pages/
|_hello.js
```

or Method B:

```
pages/
|_hello/
   |_index.js
```

Both are valid methods, however which is the better choice for scalability, user-readability, and large open-source projects.

Comment: In my opinion, you can go with index.js if you forsee multiple sub pages under hello. ie, if you are going to have `/hello/{x}` then go with mehod B. if not method A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @RGog mentioned in the comments, if you foresee multiple subpages under route `"/hello"`, then it's best to go with `"/hello/index.js"`

For example, other subroutes like `"/hello/id.js"`.

So let's say the second approach is scalable for long-term routing needs.